# Convert varchar value to date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, varchar, date-conversion

I'm converting varchar data to date in SQL server.

Table having data like below,

[image]

So it can have NULL value, proper formatted date and can have like `19900411`and  `04221995`.

So I have tried something like below, but getting error.

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(CAST(Dob AS VARCHAR), '') = '' THEN NULL
            WHEN LEN(CAST(Dob AS VARCHAR)) = '8' THEN CONVERT(
                     VARCHAR(10),
                     CONVERT(date, RIGHT(Dob, 4) + LEFT(Dob, 2) + SUBSTRING(Dob, 3, 2)),
                     103
                 )
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(Dob AS CHAR(8)), 103)
       END
FROM   TableName
WHERE  Dob IS NOT NULL
```

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

I wanted to get output as date format `MM-dd-yyyy`

*Please help me! Thanks!*

Comment: Do it in 2 steps - start by unifying your string formats, then convert to dates. If you can change the table to hold the date in a date column that would be best.

Comment: actually data would be imported to this table as flat file format so I cannot change it. not possible in 1 step?

Comment: Can you identify all date formats in your table?

Comment: not able to identify all dates, but I must have to handle dates like `04221995`

Comment: Well, is `12301123` December 30th 1123 or November 23rd 1230? It's **crucial** to be able to identify every format accurately or you end up with errors as the best case scenario or wrong dates in the worst case.

Comment: are you checked my answer

Comment: @Ajay2707 - Yes I have checked your answer and it helped me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this answer. This is work for Sqlserver 2012 and above.

Based on your discussion I created a sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE #A
( COL VARCHAR(10)
) 
INSERT INTO #A VALUES( NULL),('19900411'),('19900411'),('04-04-1976'),('10-30-1952')
insert into #A values ('04221995')
insert into #A values ('02222009 ')
select * from #a
 SELECT 
    case isdate(col ) when  1 then  CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, COL) , 105) 
        when 0 then  SUBSTRING(COL,1,2) + '-'+SUBSTRING(COL,3,2) + '-'+SUBSTRING(COL,5,4)  
        end
 FROM #A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query for your problem. It simply convert your varchar column to formatted MM-dd-yyyy

```
select convert(varchar(10), cast('2011-09-28' as date), 101)
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax. I have changed it but not success.

Comment: @pedram  I have updated my answer . Please use this. some-else has edited my answer.

Comment: thanks. but still getting error for data like `02222009`

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE #A
    ( COL VARCHAR(10)
    ) 
    INSERT INTO #A VALUES( NULL),('19900411'),('19900411'),('04-04-1976'),('10-30-1952'),('19950422')

     SELECT DATESTRINGFIELD = CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, COL) , 101) FROM #A

output
04/11/1990
04/11/1990
04/04/1976
10/30/1952
04/22/1995
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! what about this data `04221995` - table has data like this also. so can u pls provide better answer.

Comment: not working. please have some solution for data like `04221995`

Comment: i inserted that date also please check above answer

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need this:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(CAST(Dob AS VARCHAR), '') = '' THEN NULL
        WHEN LEN(CAST(Dob AS VARCHAR)) = '8' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
               CONVERT(date, RIGHT(Dob, 2) + '-' +  SUBSTRING(Dob, 5, 2) +'-' + LEFT(Dob, 4)),
               103)
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(Dob AS CHAR(10)), 103)
   END
FROM   tbl
WHERE  Dob IS NOT NULL
```

OUTPUT: `04/11/1990`

SQL Fiddle DEMO: [SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88436/2)

Comment: Getting error `Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: you could optimize this by casting the Dob

Comment: I tried it, but still getting same error. `cast(Dob AS CHAR(8)`

Comment: Getting error while showing demo - Oops! Something went wrong. Try it again and if this keeps happening, email admin@sqlfiddle.com about it.